# bluetoothctl message "Waiting to connect to bluetoothd..."

Tags: bluetooth

Current arch linux

My first attempt to use a bluetooth device, a Logitech keyboard. I inserted its dongle in usb port and from instructions on

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth

I did

```
pacman -S bluez bluez-utils
modprobe btusb
bluetoothctl
  Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
  Ctrl-C
hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0
  Can't set Simple pairing mode on hci0: Network is down (100)
```

Which network is it referring to? hci0? I can't create that till I get the MAC address, for which I need bluetoothctl

Additionally, I have also tried 'bluetoothctl -a' and adding my username to the lp line in /etc/groups, no difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have forgotten to start **bluetooth.service**.

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

If you want it to always start, make sure that you **enable** it.

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```